# Retrofit2: retrieving a JSONObject is not working

Tags: android, http, json, retrofit2

Can Retrofit2 be used to retrieve a JSONObject? What am I doing wrong in Movie.java?

**Logcat**

```
 [Movie] title: Star Wars: The Force Awakens, wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens
    rel:
```

**test.json**

```
{
  "title":"Star Wars: The Force Awakens",
  "wiki":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens",
  "release_dates": { "theater":"2015.12.17", "online":"2016.2.17", "dvd":"2016.01.17" }
}
```

**ServiceAPI.java**

```
public interface ServiceAPI {
        @GET("/txt2lrn/bollywood/test.json")
        Observable<Movie> getTestRx();
}
```

**MyApplicationB.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static ServiceAPI mService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://goanuj.freeshell.org")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        mService = retrofit.create(ServiceAPI.class);
    }

    public static ServiceAPI getServiceAPI() {
        return mService;
    }
}
```

**Movie.java**

```
public class Movie {
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private String title, wiki;
    private JSONObject release_dates;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;

    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getWiki() {
        return wiki;
    }

    public void setWiki(String wiki) {
        this.wiki = wiki;
    }

    public void setRelease_dates(JSONObject j) {
        Log.d(TAG, "j: " + j.toString());
        this.release_dates = j;
    }

    public String getRelease_dates() {
        String date = "";
        try {
            date = this.release_dates.getJSONObject("theater").toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("[Movie] title: ");
        sb.append(this.title);
        sb.append(", wiki: ").append(this.wiki);
        sb.append("\n\trel: ").append(this.getRelease_dates());
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: for  line // date = this.release_dates.getJSONObject("theater").toString();, there should be "release_dates" instead of "theater" I guess

Comment: @Nisarg I tried that but it still has the same result.

Comment: I guess date = this.release_dates.getJSONObject("theater").toString(); should be this.release_dates.getString("theater");  Also you might be getting exception in the logcat. Please keep the retrofit logs on.

Comment: Are you using GSON? what converter are you using?

Comment: And is there any exception throwed?

Comment: I added MyApplication.java; using GSON, I don't see any exceptions in the logs, but how do I turn on the Retrofit2 logging?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that in this case you should avoid the inner JSONObject and use an inner class to represent the data. For instance, create an inner `ReleaseDates` class with `theater`, `online`, and `dvd` properties, like so:

```
public class Movie {
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private String title, wiki;
    private ReleaseDates release_dates;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getWiki() {
        return wiki;
    }

    public void setWiki(String wiki) {
        this.wiki = wiki;
    }

    public void setReleaseDates(ReleaseDates releaseDates) {
        this.release_dates = releaseDates;
    }

    public ReleaseDates getReleaseDates() {
        return this.release_dates;
    }

    public static class ReleaseDates {
        private String theater;
        private String online;
        private String dvd;

        public String getTheaterReleaseDate() {
            return theater;
        }

        public String getOnlineReleaseDate() {
            return online;
        }

        public String getDvdReleaseDate() {
            return dvd;
        }
    }
}
```